# node.js spawn stdout string broken when received

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn, child-process

I have the following python code (script.py):

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def generateBeta() :
    fit = (0.075252656968743836, 498.49505071718869, 9.9999999999999991e-05, 0.18136881492296397)
    rnd = stats.beta.rvs(fit[0], fit[1], fit[2], fit[3], 581)
    rndStr = ""
    for i in rnd:
            rndStr += str(i) + ','
    print rndStr[0:len(rndStr)-1]

if __name__ =='__main__' :
    generateBeta()
```

When running "python script.py" I get something like:

0.000461650100253,0.000100731728317,0.000106550237062,0.000168159408577,0.000167330103757,0.000100050650386,0.000127253399976,0.000100193300275,0.000101258755861,0.000115222086572,0.00010000230276, ....

All in one line

When I call it using node.js child_process#spawn in the following way:

```
var sys   = require('sys'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    pyScript = spawn('python', ['./script.py']);
pyScript.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
pyScript.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The numbers get interrupted by something looking like a '\n' but is not. Somehow the stream is interrupted, i.e.

0.000461650100253,0.000100731728317,0.000106550237062,0.000168159408577,0.000167330103757,0.000100050650386,0.
000127253399976,0.000100193300275,0.000101258755861,0.000115222086572,0.00010000230276, ...

Which derives to an error on interpreting the data (i.e., causes 0.000127 later being interpreted as 127..)

Does anyone knows why such interruption occurs??

Thanks!!

Ariel.

Answer (score 0):

Per design, `console.log` writes a newline at the end of its output.

You probably want to use `process.stdout.write` instead.

http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_log_data
http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout

Comment: That does not seem to solve the issue..
Just to be more clear, if you do:

pyScript.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  var numsStr = data.split(',');
  numsStr.forEach(function(d) { process.stdout.write(d + '\n')});
});

You will get a list interrupted like this:

.
.
0.000100000110464
0.000106758505167
0.00010000000011
0.00
0103933774349
0.000119640546224
0.000100000000009
0.000101159669859
0.000100000000352

As you can see, the number 0.000103933774349 will be interpreted as 2 numbers, 0.00 and 103933774349 respectively.

Comment: It wasn't clear that that's what you were asking. The detail to understand is that when your `'data'` handler is called, it's being passed a chunk of buffered data -- it has no relationship with your data. So you can't assume it's going to be exactly one number, and therefore can't immediately insert a delimiter like `'\n'`. You'll need to collect and parse the data yourself, before outputting it, or just use any delimiters provided directly by your Python script.

Comment: Python passes a string with "," between each number. var numsStr = data.split(',') should take care of splitting this. I am collecting the data and parsing it. There's still an issue.

Comment: The issue is that you are inserting a newline I'm the middle of your data because you (by design) only get irregular pieces of your data in each call to your handler function. To help wrap your head around the issue, try removing the part where you append '\n' to the stdout.write version: all of your data will appear properly arranged on one line. If you ultimately want each number to appear on a separate line, you'll need to buffer the incoming data manually.

Comment: Python passes a string with "," between each number. var numsStr = data.split(',') should take care of splitting this. The chunk of data should keep its format, or at least not add an \n in the middle of it. If you know why this is the case, please indicate.
Thanks,

Ariel.

Comment: As noted in the original answer, \n was being added by `console.log` because that's what `console.log` is designed to do. Then, in your alternate version that uses `process.stdout.write` you add the \n yourself with `d + '\n'`. Change it to `process.stdout.write(d)` and it will be gone.

Comment: NO, that's not the case!, the problem is not an added \n by console.log. Please try the code. As I indicated 3 times, the 'break' is in the stream within data, not at the end!

Comment: I think I see your misunderstanding, now. The function you pass to `pyScript.stdout.on('data',...` is called multiple times, not just once. `pyScript.stdout` is a stream and emits *partial* chunks of the output data as they fill the stream's buffer. Your handler than takes each chunk and processes it, sending it to stdout. The newlines are appearing at the end of each of these *partial* chunks because you're inadvertently inserting them there.

Comment: Yes, I think that can be the reason. If you know how to send everything in one chunk, or how to wait until all chunks are in, then please add that as the answer!

Thanks a lot,

Ariel.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed above by adpalumbo, the event data is called for every "chunk".
The problem is solved by concatenating data and taking action after the event 'close' occurs:

```
var allData = "";
   pwScript.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      allData = allData.concat(data);
   });

pyScript.on('close', function () {
  allData.split(',').forEach(function(d) { process.stdout.write(d + '\n')});
});
```

adpalumbo, thanks for pointing this out!